# Shunt Shunt Feedback SImulations

Tags: gain, shunt, loop-gain

I am trying to simulate the solution to an old text book example on a simple Shunt-Shunt feedback amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXNsV2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The book only shows BF = 150, no other parameters for modeling.

1.) Can somebody demonstrate modeling this to get the answer from the book?  Yes, I'm not getting the same answer as the book on the forward gain, but I haven't tried trans resistance or trans conductance before.

2.) How do you simulate loop gain?  That is really what I am after.  I came back to this example after trying a different one further from the book.  The schematic below is what I think it should look like.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp6Q89.png)</sup>

From the book:

DC conditions found are IB = 25.66uA, IC = 3.849mA, VCE = 0.785 V.

Hfe = 150, Hie is calculated to be 1.020 kohms.

Partitioning the circuit into the proper modules finds f = -1/3300, Ri =400 ohms, Ro = 1.788k, the transresistance is -21.05k.

Desensitivity factor is 7.3782, and so Rif = 54.23, Rof = 242.3, Rmf = -2.8525 k, and ***Avf = -5.70***.  Output resistance is 242 and input resistance becomes 60.8 ohms.

**EDIT** - I determined the simulator (LTSpice) was causing my simulation issues with item one above, so I can at least simulate closed loop gain (-5.705 V/V).  Below is the LTSpice simulation with the edited source in series with the feedback resistor.  Is this correct?  The simulation shows voltage across the inserted source (node 2 is V2 negative and node 3 is V2 positive in the picture).

[image]

Comment: No - your loop gain test circuit is not correct. The collector node must be loaded - as during closed-loop operation.

Comment: What was the book answer for the circuit gain? I think it's going to be about 6 from a quick mental analysis.

Comment: The numbers calculated in the book are also listed in the question.  In this case gain was calculated to be -5.70.  I’m not disagreeing with the math - I can follow that.  I’m just trying to repeat these results using a simulator.

Comment: For future reference - I’m still getting used to this forum and how things work.  I modified the second figure above.  LvW responded to a different figure than what is shown now.